# Swift enum recursive associated value

Tags: math, recursion, enums, swift

I'm trying to create a math expression using an Enumeration in Swift.
This enumeration can be a constant, with an associated value of type ComplexNumber (a simple struct). It also can be a square root expression, with a recursive associated value.
For example, I want to be able to store sqrt(sqrt(1+2i)) in an enum.

```
enum Expression {
    case Sqrt(Expression)
    case Constant(ComplexNumber)
}
```

Xcode (6 beta 2) crashes immediately. What's the problem?
From what I read in the Swift guide about associated values, this should work.

Comment: it is not implemented yet. here it what i get: `error: unimplemented IR generation feature recursive enum layout`

Comment: Xcode should not crash. But I suspect that a recursive enum is not possible. Enumerations are value types and enums with associated values are similar to C unions. I assume that they must have a size that is known at compile time.

Comment: just curious is there any reason why you are Sqrt() the Expression enum type itself?

Comment: @TheLazyChap I think they want to create a formula interpreter or something along those lines, an expression is a calculation and sqrt is a calculation itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour for recursive enum in Swift (Beta 7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653541/strange-behaviour-for-recursive-enum-in-swift-beta-7)

Answer (score 1):

Now possible with Swift 2.0 since beta 4.
Examples taken from release notes:

```
 enum List<T> {
   case Nil
   indirect case Cons(head: T, tail: List<T>)
 }

 indirect enum Tree<T> {
   case Leaf(T)
   case Branch(left: Tree<T>, right: Tree<T>)
 }
```