# What is the correct way to print address for generic struct Set, to understand the implication of copy-on-write behavior?

Tags: ios, swift

This is the way for me to print out the memory address of Array, to understand the implication of copy-on-write behavior of struct.

### struct Array

```
func print(address o: UnsafeRawPointer ) {
    print(String(format: "%p", Int(bitPattern: o)))
}

var x = [1,2,3]
var y = x

// 0x600002654260
print(address: x)
// 0x600002654260   // x & y pointing to same address.
print(address: y)

x.append(4)

// 0x6000010504d0
print(address: x)   // Address changed after mutation, to avoid sharing same copy as y
// 0x600002654260
print(address: y)

x.append(5)

// 0x6000010504d0
print(address: x)   // Address remained after mutation
// 0x600002654260
print(address: y)
```

---

However, when I want to do the same study on generic `Set`, the previous way is no longer workable.

### Generic struct Set

```
func print(address o: UnsafeRawPointer ) {
    print(String(format: "%p", Int(bitPattern: o)))
}

var x : Set = [1,2,3]
var y = x

print(address: x)
print(address: y)

x.insert(4)

print(address: x)
print(address: y)

x.insert(5)

print(address: x)
print(address: y)
```

I am getting the following error when calling `print`

> cannot convert value of type 'Set' to expected argument type
> 'UnsafeRawPointer'

---

I had tried `withUnsafePointer`. But I suspect `withUnsafePointer` is not giving correct result. I am expecting both `x` and `y` should be pointing to the same address.

```
var x : Set = [1,2,3]
var y = x

// 0x000000010467c090
withUnsafePointer(to: &x) {
    print("\($0)")
}

// 0x000000010467c098
withUnsafePointer(to: &y) {
    print("\($0)")
}
```

---

What is the correct way to print address for generic struct Set, to understand the implication of copy-on-write behavior?

Comment: I don't think you would be able to see this by just writing Swift code. Unlike the array, you don't have access to the backing buffer of the set, AFAIK. Also note that it is the backing stores that are copy on write, not the struct instances themselves. This is why `withUnsafePointer` does not work.

Comment: You can, however,  go on https://godbolt.org to see the generated asm. You can see that different code are generated for the two `insert` calls (if that satisfies you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that it is not the struct instances of `Array<T>` and `Set<T>` themselves that are copy-on-write. It is their backing stores that are. If you are confused by the fact that arrays and sets have backing stores, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70393493/5133585) for a detailed description of how an array is structured. Sets are in a similar way.

Essentially, both `Array` and `Set` hold a reference to some reference type object (the backing store). If you look at the standard library source code,  you can find [`__ContiguousArrayStorage`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/29e0a31941e609bb7d19ff26dba177cdb25c9d3b/stdlib/public/core/SwiftNativeNSArray.swift#L449) and [`__RawSetStorage`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/SetStorage.swift) respectively, both of which are classes. It is this object that holds the actual elements in the collection, and it is this object that has COW behaviour. The `Array` and `Set` structs themselves behave like normal structs. After you do

```
var y = x
```

There are two `Set` structs in memory as you would expect, but they refer to the same backing store. `withUnsafePointer` gets the addresses of the two structs, which are of course different.

It's only when you modify one of them, that a new backing store object is created, and all the elements in the collection copied into the new backing store.

When you call `print(address:)` with an array, the array-to-pointer conversion actually gives you the pointer to the address of the backing store object, similar to how `Array<T>.withUnsafeBufferPointer` or `Array<T>.withUnsafeBytes` behave. Sets, on the other hand, don't have such a public API that gives you such a pointer.

You can use external tools to see the effect of COW though. A simple way is to use the Allocations instrument in Instruments.app to count how many set backing stores are allocated. Without any `insert` calls, there is only one allocation:

[image]

With one or two `x.insert` calls, there would be two allocations:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the deep detailed explanation. Reason is that, I notice when CoreData modified a content of Set A (It is previously sharing same backing store with Set B via `B = A`), the `A == B` comparison strangely return true. The strange part is that, just prior to `==` comparison, if I perform `B.count` call, `A == B` will correctly return false. So, I suspect COW mechanism is broken in between. I can "resolve" the issue, by changing `B = A` to `B = Set(A)`. But, that doesn't help me to understand the entire prob.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng So *that* is what you actually wanted to know? You seem to have asked an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. I would need a [mcve] to be able to say anything about it. All I will say now is. note that if the sets came from Core Data (which are bridged from `NSSet`s), then `==` has [different semantics](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Set.swift#L401). See also `__NativeSet.isEqual` in NativeSet.swift and `__CocoaSet.isEqual` in SetBridging.swift.

Comment: I would suggest that you post a new question about this CoreData problem, with a [mcve]. @CheokYanCheng